# Python pillow Как красить каждые n пикселей своим цветом?

Tags: python, pillow, рисование

Вот мой код, но это не тот результат.

```
def newImg():
    image = Image.open('image.jpg')
 
    w, h = image.size
    
    pixel = []
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            r, g, b = image.getpixel((x, y))
            pixel.append([r, g, b])
    
    avr = [sum(x)//len(x) for x in zip(*pixel)]
    img = Image.new('RGB', (w, h), (0,0,0,255))
    
    for i in range(0,w,4):
        for a in range(0,h,4):
            try:
                img.putpixel((i,a), (255,255,255,255))
                img.putpixel((i+1,a), (255,255,0,255))
                img.putpixel((i,a+1), (255,0,255,255))
                img.putpixel((i+1,a+1), (0,255,255,255))
            except:
                pass
    return img

wallpaper = newImg()
wallpaper.show()
```

Надо, чтобы через каждые n пикселей создавался новый квадрат из n пикселей.

**UPD**
По такой схеме скрипт должен рисовать пиксели, тут 4 пикселя

[image: Пример работы скрипта]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я неправильно поставил вопрос, я хотел пиксельную картинку. Вот решение:

```
from PIL import Image

def pixelate(image, pixel_size=8):

    image = image.resize((image.size[0] // pixel_size, image.size[1] // pixel_size), Image.NEAREST)
    image = image.resize((image.size[0] * pixel_size, image.size[1] * pixel_size), Image.NEAREST)

    return image

image = Image.open('image.jpg').convert('RGB')

image_pixelate = pixelate(image, pixel_size=16)
image_pixelate.save('output.jpg'.format(16))
image_pixelate.show()
```